# In a few days May will end. On which of the four remaining days will be ROS Indigo released?

Tags: ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In a few days May will end. So, on which of the four remaining days will be the final release ROS Indigo released?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/170446/in-a-few-days-may-will-end.-on-which-of-the-four-remaining-days-will-be-ros-indigo-released?/) by [fhurlbrink](https://answers.ros.org/users/18571/fhurlbrink/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2014-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On none of the four.

Quote @tfoote from his mail to ROS Users:

> To make sure that we have adequate testing we will delay the final release into June.

Edit: Yes you can install Beta 1 and use it.
You should receive the updates for the stable version with `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2